# how to change std::set element by call a function (call by reference)? in c++

Tags: c++, set, pass-by-reference

I am new to c++ std::set user.

Here is the question: I initialize a set in main function, and I want to insert an 
element by calling some function. But it doesn't seem to work.

Is it about call by reference or something else? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
void f(set<int> myset){
   set<int>::iterator it;
   // insert element
       for(int i=1;i<11;i++){
     myset.insert(i*10);
   }    
}   
int main ()
{
   set<int> myset;
   set<int>::iterator it;
   f(myset);
   //output element
   for(it=myset.begin();it!=myset.end();it++){
      cout<<*it<<" ";       
   } 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you need to pass by reference, otherwise you would be modifying a local copy of the set:

```
void f(set<int>& myset)
{ //           ^
  for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
     myset.insert(i*10);
}
```

Comment: To OP: As a rule of thumb, when you want the called function to modify some value from the calling function, you need to pass a reference (or a pointer). Passing by value means "copying"